# Subquery Using IN mysql Error Code: 1054

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm essentially trying to rewrite a query so that SUM(amount) is calculated as a subquery, with the database named "sakila":

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, SUM(amount) AS totalSpent
FROM sakila.customer c JOIN
     sakila.payment p
     ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY last_name, first_name;
```

What I have is:

`SELECT first_name, last_name, SUM(amount) AS totalSpent
FROM sakila.customer c
WHERE c.customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM sakila.payment p)
GROUP BY last_name, first_name;`

However, when I try to run it, it says ERROR CODE 1054, Unknown column 'amount' in 'field list'

[image: EER Diagram]

Comment: You don't have column `amount` in table customer. Check your table structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your current query, which I actually think is the way to go here:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    SUM(amount) AS totalSpent
FROM sakila.customer c
INNER JOIN sakila.payment p
    ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY
    first_name,
    last_name;
```

This is a fairly lean query because you are doing a join with a simple aggregation.  If you wanted to compute the amount as a subquery, you could do so via a correlated subquery on the `payment` table:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    SELECT(SUM(amount) FROM sakila.payment p
           WHERE p.customer_id = c.customer_id) AS totalSpent
FROM sakila.customer c;
```

Note that this query has a much highest cost because the subquery in the `SELECT` statement is *correlated* to the outer query.  This means that MySQL would have to run a separate query for *each row* of the `customer` table.  Your first query is probably the way to go here, because it would allow for things like an index and other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you encountered the `amount error` because you didn't specify which source it comes from so I checked what is your expected result and came up with this:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, SUM(p.amount) AS totalSpent
FROM sakila.customer c
    INNER JOIN payment p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.last_name, c.first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name,
       (SELECT SUM(p.amount)
        FROM sakila.payment p
        WHERE p.customer_id = c.customer_id
       ) AS totalSpent
FROM sakila.customer c;
```

This saves the aggregation in the outer query.  And it can take advantage of an index on `payment(customer_id, amount)` for performance.

Note that your query doesn't work because you can only refer to columns in tables (or views or subqueries) referenced in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes a lot more sense!